# extbase query result object values null

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have an extension, that works fine on TYPO3 6.2 and 7.4. I try to run ist on TYPO3 8.7.

The problem is, that the values of my database result object are null except uid and pid.

I use $this->subjectRepository->findAll(); and I tried to use individual queries. The result is the same.

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->statement('SELECT * FROM tx_libconnect_domain_model_subject WHERE deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0');
$query->execute();
```

This is the dump of the query:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Queryprototypeobject
   type => protected'Sub\Libconnect\Domain\Model\Subject' (35 chars)
   objectManager => protectedTYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagersingletonobjectfiltered
   dataMapper => protectedTYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMappersingletonobjectfiltered
   persistenceManager => protectedTYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManagersingletonobjectfiltered
   qomFactory => protectedTYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Qom\QueryObjectModelFactorysingletonobjectfiltered
   source => protectedTYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Qom\Selectorprototypeobject
      nodeTypeName => protected'Sub\Libconnect\Domain\Model\Subject' (35 chars)
      selectorName => protected'tx_libconnect_domain_model_subject' (34 chars)
   constraint => protectedNULL
   statement => protectedTYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Qom\Statementprototypeobject
      statement => protected'SELECT * FROM tx_libconnect_domain_model_subject WHERE deleted = 0 AND hidde
         n = 0' (81 chars)
      boundVariables => protectedarray(empty)
   orderings => protectedarray(empty)
   limit => protectedNULL
   offset => protectedNULL
   querySettings => protectedTYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettingsprototypeobject
      respectStoragePage => protectedTRUE
      storagePageIds => protectedarray(1 item)
      ignoreEnableFields => protectedFALSE
      enableFieldsToBeIgnored => protectedarray(empty)
      includeDeleted => protectedFALSE
      respectSysLanguage => protectedFALSE
      languageOverlayMode => protected'1' (1 chars)
      languageMode => protected'content_fallback' (16 chars)
      languageUid => protected0 (integer)
      usePreparedStatement => protectedFALSE
      useQueryCache => protectedTRUE
```

The dump of the result object on TYPO3 8.7:

```
object(Sub\Libconnect\Domain\Model\Subject)#886 (10) { ["title":protected]=> NULL ["dbisid":protected]=> NULL ["ezbnotation":protected]=> NULL ["uid":protected]=> int(2) ["_localizedUid":protected]=> int(2) ["_languageUid":protected]=> NULL ["_versionedUid":protected]=> int(2) ["pid":protected]=> int(1) ["_isClone":"TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject":private]=> bool(false) ["_cleanProperties":"TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject":private]=> array(5) { ["title"]=> NULL ["dbisid"]=> NULL ["ezbnotation"]=> NULL ["uid"]=> int(2) ["pid"]=> int(1) } }
```

On TYPO3 6.2:

```
object(Sub\Libconnect\Domain\Model\Subject)#1078 (10) { ["title":protected]=> string(29) "Allgemein / Fachübergreifend" ["dbisid":protected]=> string(2) "28" ["ezbnotation":protected]=> string(2) "AZ" ["uid":protected]=> int(2) ["_localizedUid":protected]=> int(2) ["_languageUid":protected]=> NULL ["_versionedUid":protected]=> int(2) ["pid":protected]=> int(1) ["_isClone":"TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject":private]=> bool(false) ["_cleanProperties":"TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject":private]=> array(5) { ["title"]=> string(29) "Allgemein / Fachübergreifend" ["dbisid"]=> string(2) "28" ["ezbnotation"]=> string(2) "AZ" ["uid"]=> int(2) ["pid"]=> int(1) } }
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921865/typo3-repository-query-returns-uid-and-pid-but-no-other-fields/69218515

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the TCA is not valid. 
There were some changes in TCA in the last major updates, e.g.:

- The required field "renderType" when using a select
- You have to use the tablename as filename for the TCA definitions
- You need to move the TCA file for each table into the folder Configuration/TCA

You can see the TCA reference here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I reworked my TCA and now it works with 8.7. ;-)

Comment: Yeah! Would be nice to mark my answer as your working solution. :)

Comment: Would also be nice if you could elaborate on your "reworking". :-) I face the same problem with a new extension (of an extension). The QueryResult holds objects of my model class, but all fields (beside uid und pid) are empty/default.